# jekyll on github pages ignores custom layout

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I'm trying to clone the repo https://github.com/TowerofHanoi/towerofhanoi.github.io on my GitHub, based on the website https://toh.necst.it and publish it on a new GitHub pages instance. I'm doing this to check that a new article is well formatted for publication.

I'm having trouble generating the website on GitHub pages, the site is somehow bad: https://mencucci.github.io/towerofhanoi.github.io/ (my repo: https://github.com/Mencucci/towerofhanoi.github.io).

Locally on my Ubuntu machine, I can get the site to render properly with the following commands:

```bash
bundle init
bundle add jekyll
rm -rf \_site && bundle exec jekyll serve --verbose
```

I couldn't get the remote to build properly.

I tried:

- adding a valid theme (no changes)
- using a custom build action (no changes)

I noticed a difference in the logs: [local](https://pastebin.com/ymjmxmhd), and [github](https://pastebin.com/2vzHfFaA). The local log references the `/_layout` directory, but the remote one does not. Maybe it doesn't "see" the theme?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, my main issue was that I was running the site using the default url, which hosts the site at `<username>.github.io/<repo_name>`. Some hard coded elements assumed that the site be hosted at domain root instead. I solved my issue by using a custom domain, which mapped the to the base domain (empty path).